# Winjs app cant connect nodejs socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, winjs

I'm build an WP app using HTML5/js/CSS, and today i got a problem. I create a NodeJs server using socket.io fot chat. My server code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');
var app = express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/chat';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
  app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3456);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , guestNumber = 1
  , nickNames = {}
  , numuser = 0;
io.set('log level', 1);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
...
});
```

In my app, i use:     `var socket = io.connect('myipserver:3456/');`

IT NOT CONNECT to my server, but when i use browser to connect my ip server, it normal, and in my app, it got error: `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd`.

In package.appxmanifest, i checked Internet ( Client & Server ) Capabilities.

So, do i miss something in my app ? Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

After some Googling I saw [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7cba42bc-0a93-4199-b767-d6e611c0e4d6/error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to?forum=winappswithhtml5) that has the same error code as your app. Seems to me that this error code says that the app does not see the server. So I don't think it's a socket-related error.

Try making a simple AJAX request to your server (with jQuery: `$.get(myipserver:3456/some-static-file)`). If it works, then it's something with the socket communications, otherwise the app does not see the server at all. Good point to start from, I guess.

Comment: Tks for reply, i found a solution, after update new socket.io version, my problem solved :)